# How do I kill the Staldra?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I have gotten killed by the Staldra four times tonight. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I know I have to hit all three heads in one stroke, but they never seem to line up so I can. If I wait to strike until they are in a diagonal line, it attacks me instead.

Is there some trick to this that I am missing?

Comment: Is Skaldra a typo or plural?

Comment: Neither? It's the enemy name?

Comment: You have Staldra in the title and Skaldra in the question body. Not having played the game, I'm not certain which is correct (or if both are - made up universes can have weird naming conventions).

Comment: I can't remember which is correct.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 different approaches I have to go against them with varying degrees of success.

1. The best and easiest way to handle them is to use a shield and **Shield Bash** them as they attack.  That will daze them for a while so you could counter.  Their heads should be lined up by then.  Note that if your shield is weak and about to break, a shield bash will not damage it.
2. Another way is to use the **Skyward Strike** on them.  You just have to slash in the orientation that their heads are in.  This one isn't too reliable as you have to anticipate their moves (and need some luck).
3. Probably the hardest way to deal with them is to fight "head-on."  When they're about to strike, their heads will be oriented in a certain way.  If you have a fast enough reaction time and close enough to attack, you could slash in the same orientation to kill them off.  A more cautious approach would dodge back first when they do attack and counter.  I don't remember what their orientations are after they attack but it will probably be in the same as when they attacked or horizontal.  You may have to experiment with that.

Probably the least successful way to deal with them would be to randomly attack them.  Their heads will mostly be not lined up so you won't be able to kill them that way.  Wait for them using the tips above to kill them.

Comment: I find letting them clonk themselves dizzy off the shield and then spamming them with sword swipes works within a couple of tries.

Answer (score 6):

They line up just before they're about to attack, as you've no doubt realised. What you might not have noticed is that, if you don't hit all the heads, there's a small window while it's regenerating where you canfrantically swipe at the remaining head. If you get it before the other heads grow back, it'll die just the same.

I think I've killed them the proper way once.

Comment: try to hit two heads at the same time, flail with sword to hit the third <- my usual modus operandi.

Answer (score 2):

Just use bombs. They're a one-hit kill.

Comment: That only helps if I have bombs, which I don't at the moment, but I will keep that in mind for when I do.

Answer (score 1):

Right before they strike, their heads line up. One way to cut them off all at once is to be quick enough to go for a side slash just at this moment, but it's tricky.

Another way is a diagonal slash when the heads are in diagonal alignment.

You can also shield bash, although you need a good strong shield to make sure it doesn't break.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Doing a shield bash at the right moment won't actually damage the shield, it will be blocked with ill effect.  It's the blocks when the shield is out and you don't do a shield bash that it gets damaged.  So if you do a shield bash when you need to block every time, your shield will be practically indestructible.

Answer (score 1):

Take out a head or two, then horizontal spin attack when they reform.

works like a charm.

If you mess up, hit em again then take it from the top.

Don't bother trying to counter, it's not worth getting hit (I tried.)

Answer (score -4):

3 words: horizontal spin attack